# Ubuntu 12.04 Eclipse Java Neon

Tags: java, eclipse

When I try to open Eclipse neon downloaded from the official side I get this error:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/home/jan/Java/Javax64/jre1.8.0_101/bin/java
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=Link removed due to link restriction
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->Link removed due to link restriction
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false
-jar /home/jan/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/jan/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/jan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444/eclipse_1617.so
-startup /home/jan/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 488006
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /home/jan/Java/Javax64/jre1.8.0_101/bin/java
-vmargs
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=Link removed due to link restriction
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->Link removed due to link restriction
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false
-jar /home/jan/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
```

The java version is downloaded directly from their own side.

Answer (score 0):

Exit code 13 pretty much always means you have a mix of 32 and 64 bit code.

You are using a 64 bit Eclipse (the launcher has `x86_64` in the name) so you must be using a 32 bit Java.

You must use a 32 bit Eclipse and 32 bit Java or 64 bit Eclipse and 64 bit Java.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by downloading the package eclipse-platform. However this also returned an error but was much easier to find a solution to ;)